# Optimizing blockchain token purchase. Finding maximum value of a function.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am working on smart contract on ethereum blockchain. The idea is that using some specified amount of money I have to buy maximum number of tokens from two different token smart contracts. Those two smart contracts calculate number of tokens to be sold using two different functions.

> Contract 1 - C-ORG by Fairmint.

$$F1(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2x}{b} + a^2} - a$$

where **b** and **a** are constant values.

> Contract 2 - Uniswap Token Traiding Contract.

$$F2(x) = \frac{x*d*997}{g*1000 + x * 997}$$

where d and g are constant.

What I need to do is split my aount of money I have between those two contracts so in total I can get maximum number of tokens possible from those two contracts combined.

So my understanding is that I have to find a maximum value of function
$$F3(x) = F1(z) + F(x-z)$$
where z is amount of money spend on contract 1 and
$z <= x$ and $z>0$

So I can say that 
$$F3(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2} - a  + \frac{(x-z)*d*997}{g*1000 + (x-z) * 997} $$

What I need to do is I have to find value of z, knowing value of x, for which this function will give maximum result.

I am not good in calculus so I used [Integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and it came back with equation like this: 
$$\dfrac{1000dg\ln\left(\left|997\left(x-z\right)-1000g\right|\right)}{997}+\dfrac{\left(2x+a^2b\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{3\sqrt{b}}+dx-ax$$

And now I understand that I have to find value of z where this function will be equal zero. Right ?
$$\dfrac{1000dg\ln\left(\left|997\left(x-z\right)-1000g\right|\right)}{997}+\dfrac{\left(2x+a^2b\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{3\sqrt{b}}+dx-ax = 0$$

> I have following questions:

1. Is my thinking correct. Should I do it this way ?
2. Is result of calculus correct ?
3. How I can be sure I found maximum and not minimum ?
4. How I can simplify last function so it is easier to calculate. I am working in coding language ( solidity ) which only support basic mathematical functions (add,sub,mul,div and  binary operations). I don't have anything for $\sqrt a$ or $\ln$

Any help will be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the maximums and/or minimums of a function, you should take the derivative of it, not the integral. As you basically stated, your function is

$$F3(z; x) = \sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2} - a  + \frac{(x-z)*d*997}{g*1000 + (x-z) * 997} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

In this case, $x$ is some given amount and $z$ is your variable. Thus, you want to take the derivative of \eqref{eq1} with respect to $z$. Doing this gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\left(F3(z; x)\right)}{dz} & = \frac{1}{b\sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2}} - \frac{997d}{1000g + 997(x-z)} + \frac{997^2d(x - z)}{\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{b\sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2}} + \frac{-997d\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right) + 997^2d(x - z)}{\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{b\sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2}} - \frac{997d(1000g)}{\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

The maximum and minimum values will occur at the end-points, i.e., where $z = 0$ or $z = x$, or where the expression in \eqref{eq2} is $0$. As for determining the latter, you can equate both terms to each other, cross-multiply, square and collect the terms in $z$ together to get a quartic polynomial. In particular, first let $c = 997d(1000g)$ to make the algebra a bit simpler. You then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{b\sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2}} & = \frac{c}{\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^2} \\
\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^2 & = cb\sqrt{\frac{2z}{b} + a^2} \\
\left(1000g + 997(x-z)\right)^4 & = \left(cb\right)^2\left(\frac{2z}{b} + a^2\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

I'll leave it to you to do the multiplications and collection of terms if you wish. As for finding its roots, there's actually an analytic solution, such as described in Wikipedia's [Quartic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) article, but it's somewhat long & messy. As an easier alternative, there are many root finding algorithms, such as described in Wikipedia's [Root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) article. I don't believe you'll need anything fancy, so even on those basic numerical methods will likely work well enough for you.

Regarding whether you have a maximum or minimum at some point, say $z_1$, you would normally check the second derivative at $z_1$, with it being negative meaning $f$ is a maximum at $z_1$, and it being positive meaning $f$ is a minimum at $z_1$. In your case, as there won't likely be an issue of these points being too close together, you may wish to just check the $f$ values at $z_1$, just a bit less than $z_1$, and just a bit more than $z_1$, to compare them & determine if it's a maximum or minimum.

As for handling the expression on a computer, there's apparently just the complication of determining the square root. Fortunately, there are relatively simple, but quite efficient, square root determination algorithms. For example, Wikipedia's [Methods of computing square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) has some excellent suggestions, with likely even any fairly basic one they mention being sufficient for your needs.